# Any way to open this Xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to open [this N64 emulator for iOS](https://github.com/zodttd/n64ios) in Xcode, but I'm having a bit of trouble.

There is no .xcodeproj file and the project was authored at least 2 years ago, so I'm wondering if it's even compatible with the current version of Xcode/iOS SDK.

Comment: What is the error do you get? Have you imported this to your local git or saved the code as zip?

Comment: I tried importing it, saving it and creating a new project and importing all the files manually. I got this error among others: "The scheme 'Framework' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64–bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode." I suspect it is a compatibility issue but have been trying to figure it out for a day or two now and haven't found any clear explanation.

Comment: Try contacting the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error you mentioned signifies  XCode project is not able to find the required library, or it finds one but its not compatible with your current operating system/processor/build settings. The following steps can solve it:

```
your project -> target -> Build Setting

Modify following items: 1.Base SDK ; 2.Architectures.
```

And then clean and build the application